# How to grab Attachment ID on JIRA Issue Page using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jira

I am using an ajax call to whose url needs the attachment id. I am using a hardcoded url right now which is url: AJS.contextPath()+"/rest/api/latest/attachment/10415"

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: AJS.contextPath()+"/rest/api/latest/attachment/10415",
TYPE: "GET",
//dataType: "application/json",
dataType: "text",
success: function(data){
    console.log("Success");
},
error: function(data){
    console.error("Error with attachments");
},
}).done(function(data){     
console.log("Done with greying attachments");
});
```

So this only works for the attachment with id 10415. I was thinking of making 2 ajax calls, the above one being the second. And the first having a url of AJS.contextPath()+"/rest/api/latest/issue/${issueId} which returns the content url of the above ajax call.

I am new to ajax so I am not sure if this will work. Also, should the dataType be "text" or "application/json"?

Comment: your done function has `data`, console.log it :)

Comment: well no because i want it to work with other attachment ids, not just 10415 so i need a way to grab the attachment id. thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered a simular question hhttps://answers.atlassian.com/questions/278734/how-to-grab-attachment-id-on-issue-page-using-js